# Sending Mail and SMS using Twilio in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, twilio, postback

I want to send Verification code to user when it select Email then Verifi-code sending to User in UserEmail and if User Select Phone then Verifi-code sending to user in his phone using

In My code I take one DropDownList(with AutoPostBack=true) Using that user can select their Choice

But My Code is not working

**Verify.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ }

protected void dpd_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String email = Request.QueryString["email"];
    String phn = "+91" + Request.QueryString["phn"];
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (dpd.SelectedValue.Equals("Email"))
        {
            var chars = 
       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var stringChars = new char[8];
            var random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
            {
                stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }
            var finalString = new String(stringChars);
            String mailbody = @"

<html><head></head><body><div style=background:#000099;border:1px solid 
#000099;padding: 10px;><img src='+logo.png+' /></div><br /><br /><hr 
style=color:#FF0000><p><strong>Hello User</strong>,<br />  <font face=Arial, 
Helvetica, sans-serif color=#66CCFF size=+1>Please Verify Your your account 
information</font></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Thanks For Joining Us...<br>  
<strong>Gaurav Bothra</strong></p></body></html>";

            // Specify the from and to email address
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("keystroke165@gmail.com", email);
            // Specify the email body
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.Body = mailbody;
            // Specify the email Subject
            mailMessage.Subject = "Welcome to THERAPEUTIC";

            // No need to specify the SMTP settings as these 
            // are already specified in web.config
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            // Finall send the email message using Send() method
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        if (dpd.SelectedValue.Equals("Phone"))
        {
            var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var stringChars = new char[8];
            var random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
            {
                stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }

            var finalString = new String(stringChars);

            var accountSid = "MYSIDXXXXX";
            // Your Auth Token from twilio.com/console
            var authToken = "MYTOKENXXXX";

            TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

            var message = MessageResource.Create(
                to: new PhoneNumber(phn),
                from: new PhoneNumber("MYTwilioNO"),
                body: "Hello User\nPlease Verify Your your account information\nyour otp is\n" + finalString);
            ///End
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Describe not working. You need to say what it's doing, mention any errors, describe other things you've tried.

Comment: No error But mail and sms is not receiving

Comment: Have you stepped through the code with the debugger to verify it takes the correct path through your code?

Comment: I debug my code in code there is no logical problem

Comment: Really? It took the path you expected through the code as you watched it execute line by line? I don't believe you.

Comment: Do you know what a postback is, and why you would check for one?

Comment: Code is working on right path

Comment: ya I know what is postback and why i used it

Comment: Again, I don't believe you. `dpd_SelectedIndexChanged` fired in response to some drop down list being changed, right? Therefore, the only situation in which it will fire is *during a postback*. And within that function, the bulk of the logic executes only when it is *not a postback*. Therefore, the reason I don't believe that you actually stepped through your code line by line to verify that it's taking the correct path through the code, and the reason I don't believe you know what a postback is. You know, it's okay to say you don't know what something is?

Comment: If you don't know what something is or means, say so! If you don't know how to step through the debugger, then look up how to do so or ask how. If you don't know what a postback is or why you would check for one, then look it up or ask! Pretending you know what they are when you don't is just going to delay your understanding.

Comment: I now what is postback its mean a webpage is loading second time

Comment: What do you think `if (!IsPostBack)` means?

Comment: Thanks a lot i just copy and paste my another file i forgot to remove not postback Thnaku once again

Comment: You would have found that in under 30 seconds if you set a breakpoint in your code on the first line of the method and then stepped through it line by line, or added logging to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This event normally only fires when a a DropDownList has it's selected index changed and raises a postback that calls `dpd_SelectedIndexChanged`. However, the bulk of your logic is wrapped in:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
```

and so the logic to send an email or text message is never reached. You need to remove the if statement.

These sorts of errors when the code takes an unexpected path can easily be found by [using the debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx) to step through your code or adding logging.